# Zend and Social Engine 4 - getting zend database configuration information

Tags: php, zend-framework

Before hand - Thanks for any help regarding this issue!
Currently we are running social engine 4.8.7
We are currently trying to get information about the default Zend database configuration settings and we are new to Zend framework.

The internet has yielded many answers in which none work... 
In our controller we have tried:

```
$this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOptions()
```

- Fatal error: Call to undefined method ::getInvokeArg()

```
new Zend_Config($this->getOptions());
```

- Fatal error: Call to undefined method ::getOptions()

```
$this->application->getOptions()
```

- Fatal error: Call to undefined method ::getOptions()

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getOptions();
```

- returns an empty array " array(0) { } "

```
Zend_Registry::get('db')
```

- gives NULL

```
Zend_Registry::getInstance()['DB']
```

- gives NULL

and we have tried many other suggestions which either give null or a fatal errors from our controller.php

At current this is our temporary solution which is not elegant at all but works:

```
$config = new Zend_Config(include 'application/settings/database.php');
$config->adapter
```

which gives us "mysqli".  The above can also be used for retrieving most database configuration information but causes - serious security concerns.

Is there a correct way of getting this same information from Zend without having to access the file directly?

Thanks

Comment: Have you extended your controller with Zend_Controller_Action??

Comment: Our controller by default already extends Engine_Content_Widget_Abstract and there is no support for multi-inheritance.  I suppose we could just make a separate class which extends Zend_Controller_Action then instantiate it in our current controller but isn't there already an object in memory that we can pull this info from?

Comment: Sorry to say this but i don't know much about social engine. This might help you.. https://faysalahmed.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/code-for-how-to-work-with-database-in-socialengine

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

/**
 * @var Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract $adapter
 */

$adapter = Engine_Api::_()->getModuleBootstrap('core')->getContainer()->offsetGet('db');
$config = $adapter->getConfig();
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?